# how to bind 2D texture on 3d Sphere

Tags: c++, opengl

I am done with my sphere,its movements and all . I am just struck on texture stuff. Not able to load even a simple texture.
So anyone have any idea about it enlighten me.

Comment: Please post code covering the section you believe is malfunctioning.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. I'll post it as soon as possible.

Comment: i am not able to add the code in the comment . I have asked the same question with the whole code what I am trying. @Andreas

Comment: the question is "texture mapping on a 3d sphere with opengl using c++"

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give u very basic Info:

First of all you need to learn about texture coordinates. It will have x and y components.Both components will range 0 to 1.[image: Basic texture]

To add texture to any mesh/object you need provide texture coords.For simple rectangle mesh with image, they will be (0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)

Like wise you need to calculate tex coords for your sphere also. U can do the same while generating vertices for your sphere. These generated tex coords which will have their X and Y components in range [0,1] and wrap given rectangular/square image around the sphere.

Sample flow:
tex corrds array -> vbo ->shader -> shader sampler -> pixel set to framebuffer

Comment: thanks for your help. I have asked the same question along with my code, so you can look into it. @Raki